# Interpolating and subtracting two sets of data

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, interpolation, data, dataset

I have a data set "data9k" with x varying from 0 to 365, and another data "data0" set with x varying from 0 to 365. But the x values for both data sets are not same but similar. I want to subtract the y values of "data0" from "data9k". I am assuming I should first interpolate both data9k and data0 from 0 to 360 [I only want the 0 to 360 range] and then subtract them? How should I interpolate? Is there a better way to do this?

Here are my data sets

```
data9k = {{1.1172, 4.62*10^-8}, {12.619, 4.47*10^-8}, {24.638, 
  4.44*10^-8}, {35.7164, 4.34*10^-8}, {47.7885, 4.14*10^-8}, {59.3201,
   4.14*10^-8}, {71.6327, 3.83*10^-8}, {83.2878, 
  3.44*10^-8}, {94.4534, 3.39*10^-8}, {106.053, 3.06*10^-8}, {118.451,
   3.16*10^-8}, {130.402, 3.32*10^-8}, {142.897, 
  3.59*10^-8}, {155.719, 4.02*10^-8}, {167.718, 4.35*10^-8}, {179.867,
   4.85*10^-8}, {191.746, 4.8*10^-8}, {203.29, 4.99*10^-8}, {215.511, 
  5.43*10^-8}, {227.228, 5.56*10^-8}, {238.653, 6.02*10^-8}, {251.438,
   5.83*10^-8}, {263.693, 5.85*10^-8}, {275.223, 
  5.27*10^-8}, {287.595, 5.01*10^-8}, {299.263, 5.01*10^-8}, {310.811,
   4.85*10^-8}, {322.76, 4.94*10^-8}, {334.224, 4.99*10^-8}, {346.385,
   4.84*10^-8}, {358.353, 4.84*10^-8}, {365.005, 
  4.39*10^-8}, {365.005, 4.68*10^-8}};
data0 = {{1.72155, 6.26*10^-8}, {13.866, 6.02*10^-8}, {25.3934, 
  5.76*10^-8}, {36.5356, 5.38*10^-8}, {48.7993, 5.24*10^-8}, {60.9991,
   5.12*10^-8}, {72.9415, 5.*10^-8}, {84.1156, 4.91*10^-8}, {95.8728, 
  5.01*10^-8}, {108.136, 5.08*10^-8}, {119.668, 5.06*10^-8}, {131.259,
   5.25*10^-8}, {142.742, 5.31*10^-8}, {154.806, 
  5.62*10^-8}, {166.376, 5.82*10^-8}, {177.496, 5.89*10^-8}, {189.637,
   6.1*10^-8}, {202.158, 6.35*10^-8}, {214.349, 6.57*10^-8}, {226.658,
   6.74*10^-8}, {238.496, 6.77*10^-8}, {250.744, 
  6.87*10^-8}, {262.746, 6.91*10^-8}, {274.316, 6.94*10^-8}, {286.446,
   6.92*10^-8}, {298.52, 6.95*10^-8}, {310.33, 6.76*10^-8}, {322.292, 
  6.57*10^-8}, {334.268, 6.45*10^-8}, {345.836, 6.16*10^-8}, {357.444,
   5.97*10^-8}, {364.946, 5.85*10^-8}, {365.005, 5.92*10^-8}};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if0 = Interpolation[data0, 
   "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Automatic, "WarningMessage" -> False}];

difference = {#, #2 - if0 @ #} & @@@ data9k;

ListLinePlot[{data0, data9k, difference}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotLegends -> {"data0", "data9k", "difference"}]
```

[image]

An alternative approach is to use [`TemporalData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html):

```
td0 = TemporalData[#2, {#}, ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", 
       InterpolationOrder -> 1}] & @@ Transpose @ data0;

difference2 = Quiet @ {#, #2 - td0["PathFunction"] @ #} & @@@ data9k;

ListLinePlot[{data0, data9k, difference2}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotLegends -> {"data0", "data9k", "difference"}]
```

[image]